# Adding elements to an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, haml

I receive the following object

```
@list = 
 {
    "total": 2,
    "items": [
        {

            "name": "hello",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": "100"
                }
            ]
        },
        {

            "name": "SOME NAME",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": "120"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to create and array of all the values. Something like `[100,120]`. How do I do that. 
I tried,

```
- list.items.each do |item, arr = [], name = []|
-arr.push(item.values); name.push(item.name)
  - y = arr
  - x = names
```

In this case,
I get only one value at a time. in the first iteration I have `[100]` and in the second iteration I have `[120]`. What am I doing wrong.?

Update: I've edited what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Both `y` and `x` should contain the array of values and names respectively.

Comment: What kind of object is it? How are you receiving it? The plural `"values"` key is curious. Is it possible you'll get more than one value per item? What if two values are identical?

Comment: it's `json`. it's not a valid ruby array.  `list.items` not valid hash access in ruby.

Comment: `list` is a class with which I access the `items` object.

Comment: That doesn't answer my first question. What kind of object is it? Are you using a library like HTTParty to parse a JSON response? You have misrepresented it above.

Comment: `@list` is a hash, not a string. This has nothing to do with JSON unless the OP intended it to be a string. I see no no basis for drawing that conclusion.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The fact that OP is using methods like `.items` means that he's using some class which encapsulates the hash. More often than not on SO this type of thing is a parsed response from a service. It's not necessarily JSON, but we don't know what it is.

Comment: @Mark, just to be clear, for it to be JSON, `@list` would have to be a string, so you're arguing that the OP forgot the quotes. Correct?. I'm not being flippant as I've never worked with JSON.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here we need 4 things:

1. Getting a key from a hash: `hash[:key]`
2. `Array#map`: `[1, 2, 3].map { |number| number**2 } # => [1, 4, 9]`
3. `Array#flatten`: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]].flatten # => [1, 2, 3, 4]`
4. `String#to_i`: `'44'.to_i # => 44`

---

```
@list[:items].map { |item| item[:values].map { |value| value[:value] } }.flatten.map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that like so:

```
@list[:items].map { |h| h[:values].first[:value].to_i }
  #=> [100, 120]
```

If, unlike the example, `h[:values]` could have more than one element:

```
@list[:items].flat_map { |h| h[:values].map { |g| g[:value].to_i } }
```

Comment: Add a clarification that this assumes `values` to have only one `value`. Also add `map(&:to_i)`

Comment: @Cary Always test... @list[:items] returns nil as the key is a string.. Please test

Comment: @Зелёный, please explain.

Comment: do you see the OP code snippet? It's the `JSON` object not a ruby `hash`.

Comment: @Зелёный, I don't know much about JSON, but I thought they were strings. ndn, strike 'also'.

Comment: i just wonder how you can use the ruby hash syntax with a json object. Only after parse it and convert to valid ruby `hash`. `{ "total": 2 }` - it's JSON. `{ total: 2 }` - it's ruby

Comment: @Зелёный, why would that matter? The question was about Ruby, it doesn't have JSON tag. This was a simple Ruby question about accessing values in nested hashes/arrays. Being a valid JSON has nothing to do with it...

Comment: so i can post `C#` code for the `Java` question? Just because it's similar the syntax?

Comment: @Зелёный, as long as you are asking a question about Java, the fact that supposedly the same code is also a valid C# code doesn't matter.

Comment: @Зелёный, please explain this: `require 'json'; @list.respond_to? :parse #=> false`. It's not a string! Admit it!

Comment: @CarySwoveland okey, i think i should stop it. Edit your question, i upvote.

Comment: No, you should either admit you were wrong or delete all you comments! No editing is required. It has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @Зелёный, seriously dude. This is as if a question was asking *"How can I add numbers in Ruby"* and you saying *"This has nothing to do with Ruby, it's a math question"* because there is `2 + 2` as part of the description.

Comment: I will be having this code in haml. It wont let me access the array outside of the `{ }`

Comment: @Зелёный, assuming that you agree that your initial reaction was inappropriate  and that you are one of the downvoters, could you please remove the downvotes?

Comment: @ndn only if you edit question. SO do not allow me reverse downvote, only after editing.

Comment: @Зелёный, what do you want me to edit? I agree that the formatting is far from perfect. But I disagree that there should be any clarification about this being a regular Ruby question and not one about JSON as the default assumption should be it is not, if it wasn't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: StackOverflow rules do not allow me reverse downvote, only after editing. Just edit something, anything. http://i.imgur.com/WAyRegh.png